# Why Parashurama taught art of warfare to Kshatriya(s)?

Tags: mahabharata, parashurama, kshatriya

Guru Drona's guru Parashurama was against teaching to Kshatriyas. However he still taught to Bhishma. In the similar way, Drupad and Drona were considered *Guru-Bhai*; probably that means Parashurama also taught to Drupad. Why?

Comment: Bhishma & Karna were also Parashurama's Shishya.

Comment: @iammilind  -  yes in case of karna he didn't know karna is khsatriya and for Bhishma I edited in Question  thanks

Comment: Parashurama didnt teach Drupad Drona went to him only when he heard that the Avatar was giving away all his weapons. But yes the question of why he taught Bhishma is a valid one.

Answer (score 1):

Guru Drona was the son of rishi Bharadwaja. Both Drona and Drupada studied under the guidance of rishi Bharadwaja. Also, when Guru Parshurama was giving gifts to all brahmans, Drona reached there. Only the weapons of rishi Parshurama were left. Hence, the weapons and the knowledge to use them was given.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.